# What is ActiveX container?

Tags: delphi, activex, containers, intranet

I never really got the chance to do anything with Microsoft ActiveX in all of my programming career. So, I have very little knowledge of what it is or what it is used for. Although I've searched on the Internet for answer, I found many different definition for ActiveX or ActiveX Container. One of my customer is asking for ActiveX Container for my software which I don't have. He wants view or take control of my software remotely through this ActiveX Container. Is this possible? Also, is ActiveX still around? I am trying to see if I can put this ActiveX container real quick for him to use.

I am assuming that ActiveX is used to expose some part of your software to the Internet or the Intranet. So, that the user can get access to your application remotely.

Any response will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Activex container is a frame where An ActiveX control can run, These containers can be embedded in a Desktop app or a Web page.

Due which the ActiveX control contains native code you must setup the security settings of your browser in order to run this kind of objects. The only browser where the ActiveX is fully supported is IE (exist some experimental projects to support Activex in Firefox and chrome) Also these containers only can run under Windows.

The fastest way to convert your existing app into a ActiveX Control , is using a [TActiveForm](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.AxCtrls.TActiveForm) (below you have a link with a sample).

For more information try these links

- [`Introduction to ActiveX Control Containers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Wrapping a Delphi TFrame descendant as an ActiveX control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066015/wrapping-a-delphi-tframe-descendant-as-an-activex-control)